# Why is .ajax() able to call WebMethod but not .get()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

The .ajax version works fine when I use it, but the .get doesn't call the WebMethod but instead just returns the html of the page. Is there a way to change it or should I just always use the .get function?

**.ajax() version**

```
    var ajaxUrl = "/MainPage.aspx/GetCharactersAjaxGet";
    var data = '{}';

     await $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json'
     }).done(function (data) {
         characters = data.d;
         characters.unshift({ Id: 0, CharacterName: '', SortBy: 0 });
         console.log(characters);
     }).fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert(xhr);
     });
```

**.get() version**

```
const successFunction = function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {;
        alert("success");
        console.log(data);
    }

await $.get(ajaxUrl, data, successFunction);
```

**asp.net code** Edit:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<Move> GetCharactersAjaxGet()
{
    var lst = new List < Character > ();

    IWorkbook workbook;
    using(FileStream file = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    }
    
    var importer = new Mapper(workbook);
    var items = importer.Take < Character > (0);
    
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if (item != null) {
            lst.Add(item?.Value);
        }
    }
    
    return lst;

}
```

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Comment: `$.get()` is just a shorcut for `$.ajax({ method: "get" })` (nothing more so you're missing those options from the `$.ajax()` call)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would advise using `$.getJSON()`. This will help with the Content Type. That appears to be the only difference that I can see.

Comment: I switched to .getJSON() but my problem is that it's still getting the HTML Page and not calling the webmethod like it would with .ajax().

Comment: @bsdatastuff2 it sounds like the resulting payload is HTML and not JSON. Can you share your backend code for `MainPage.aspx/GetCharactersAjaxGet`. It seems like it is confused by the GET request itself.

Comment: I edited the previous code.

Comment: when you pass "data" in the call, it seems to be set to "{}".  I'm guessing that's being appended to the URL in an odd way.   I would leave out "data", since it's empty anyway, and your action/method doesn't require any arguments.  So just use: $.get(ajaxUrl, successFunction);

Comment: Does [this](https://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/12/03/usehttpget-needs-you-to-enable-httpget-in-the-webconfig/) help?

Comment: @wazz It didn't. I wouldn't have thought so before I tried it since the .ajax function works without it.

Comment: @pcalkins I tried that. The issue is the WebMethod isn't called and that call just retrieves the html of that page instead.